# PHP button in a for each loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am displaying user details on a form using a for each loop. In the for each loop i am adding a button below the user details to delete the information for each user.

```
<?php
foreach( $Names as $Name )
    {

        $dbQuery = $db->prepare("select * from user WHERE Name = ?");
        $dbQuery->execute(array($Name));
        while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $ID = $dbRow['ID']; 
            $Email = $dbRow ['Email'];
        }
        ?>


    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="hotel_id" class=" col-sm-4 control-label">ID:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ID" name="ID[]" placeholder="Enter City Name" value="<?php echo $ID?>">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name[]" value="<?php echo $Name?>">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email[]" value="<?php echo $Email ?>">
    </div>
    </div>

        <div class ="form-group">
<label for="removeUser" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <input id="removeUser" name="removeUser" type="submit" value="Remove this user" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to completely remove this user?');">
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }

?>
```

I know how to delete the users but the problem i am having is that i cant seem to get the id for the specific user when the button is clicked. So far i have only been able to retrieve the last id displayed or all of the id's displayed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This happens because the values of `$ID` and `$Email` will change for every loop. Therefore, the values that are used in the HTML will be based on the ones fetched in the last db query. Also, it is not efficient to have a query run inside a foreach loop. Try `WHERE   IN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to **move the closing loop brace to the end of the html of each row**. Then I recomend you to do a separated URL for deleting a record, and changing the submit button to a anchor tag (by CSS rules you can make it to look like a button), so the anchor will be:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $ID?>" class="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to completely remove this user?');">Delete</a>
```

So in the backend of **delete.php** you'll have something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $dbQuery = $db->prepare(sprintf("DELETE FROM user WHERE ID = %s", $_GET['id']));
    $dbQuery->execute(array($Name));
}
```

You'll need to improve this delete query so it will be safe, because people might send you SQL code trough `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is wrong, because last one is fetched and then html is rendered. Try add that html under while loop

Answer (score 0):

Please add ID in hidden filed in a form. So you can get id each form submit like normal form field value. Add ID to hidden field value.